# É possivel exibir os dados de uma tabela separadamente?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela no meu banco de dados e ela contem uma coluna com os seguintes dados:

```
link.com/1, link.com/2, link.com/3, link.com/4
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se tem como eu fazer a consulta no PHP e retornar o valor da coluna onde cada valor venha só até á `,` numa linha e o outro em outra linha assim:

```
link.com/1

link.com/2

link.com/3

link.com/4
```

Há alguma possibilidade de fazer dessa forma?

Answer (score 0):

Podes dividir a string através da vírgula, para isso usa a função [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
<?php

$retorno_bd = "link.com/1, link.com/2, link.com/3, link.com/4";

// converte a string em um array
// utiliza a "," para fazer a divisao
$array = explode( ",", $retorno_bd);


foreach($array as $linha){
    echo "$linha \n";
}

?>
```

[Veja o código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/e.js/t93Me6)